# Page breaks on php tag

Tags: php, html

The following code is written in php file and breaks page

```
<?php

$myrows1=cpabc_player_plan();

foreach ($myrows1 as $index=>$item1) //start foreach party plan
{  
    if ($item1 === reset($myrows1))
    {}
?>

<?php }?>
```

while if I use it as

```
<?php
$myrows1=cpabc_player_plan();

foreach ($myrows1 as $index=>$item1) //start foreach party plan
{
  if ($item1 === reset($myrows1))
    {}
}?>
```

then it works fine.

Comment: I think there's other markup involved in this that's causing the issue. [Here's a proof of concept with your code that works fine](https://eval.in/571728)

Comment: No, the function issue is not there

Comment: I have tried it as well $myrows1=array();//cpabc_player_plan();

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach():  endforeach Block like this:

```
<?php foreach ($myrows1 as $index=>$item1): ?>
  <h1> some html tags</h1>
   <?php
     if ($item1 === reset($myrows1))
       {}
   ?>
  <h1> some html tags</h1>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

for other php statements you can read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) page.